# Trying to add a namespace with XmlTextWriter using a memorystream

Tags: c#, xml, xml-namespaces

**NOTE** I am limited to .NET 2.0

I need to add a namespace using a XmlTextWriter.  I am not reading in a Xml Document or saving it out.  At first I was thinking I could use the XmlNameSpaceManager to add a namespace, but this appears to be in the case I have read in a xml document or working with an XmlDocument object.

Maybe I am over complicating this as I will only be dealing with one namespace at a time.  It appears I could just add a root element with an attribute to manually create the namespace since it is on the root element.

An Example of what I need to create:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<abcElement xmlns="urn:schemas-acme-com:transaction-data-1.1">

</abcElement>
```

Would there be a problem with doing something like:

```
xtw.WriteStartDocument();
xtw.WriteStartElement("abcElement");
xtw.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "urn:schemas-acme-com:transaction-data-1.1");
xtw.WriteEndElement();
```

Or is there an issue with this?

Comment: FYI, you should not use `XmlTextWriter`. Use `XmlWriter.Create` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not try to output xmlns by hand. Use another overide of WriteStartElement instead - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7cdfkth5.aspx

```
writer.WriteStartElement(prefix, "ISBN", "urn:samples");
```

Answer (score 0):

You might get more mileage out of XNamespace and XElement later on when you're adding other elements.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387075.aspx

Comment: I forgot to mention (but have added now) that I am working in a .Net 2.0 project so this would not be available to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
xtw.WriteStartElement("abcElement");
xtw.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "urn:schemas-acme-com:transaction-data-1.1");
```

Should be

```
xtw.WriteStartElement("abcElement", "urn:schemas-acme-com:transaction-data-1.1");
```